# Converting regex_substr and listagg code over to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, sql-server-2012

I'm looking for a bit of help. I'm converting something over from Oracle to SQL Server, and am in a pickle.

```
select distinct
    field1, field2, 
    regexp_substr(path, '[^/]+', 1, column_value) elem
from 
    grouped,
    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
                        connect by level <= regexp_count(path,'/')) as sys.odciNumberList))
                        where regexp_substr(path, '[^/]+', 1, column_value) is not null),
     result as (
       select field1, field2,
              dense_rank()
               over (order by listagg(elem,',') within group (order by elem))
                grp
      from split
      group by field1, field2
```

I'm under the impression that using the STUFF function would be a likely alternative to the `listagg()` function, but in order to get that far I need to figure out how to convert the `regex_substr()` code over to SQL Server 2012.

The sample data :

```
field1      field2
--------------------------------
02598559  | /04460516
04355059  | /04460576/05339398
04352043  | /04461255
--------------------------------
```

What's the best way to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the rest of the logic, but this will split the delimited string into a table that I'm sure you can work into the rest of the query:

This is the test data:

```
declare @t table(f1 varchar(10), f2 varchar(50))
insert @t values ('02598559','/04460516'),('04355059','/04460576/05339398'),('04352043','/04461255')
select * from @t
```

This is the data split into rows:

```
SELECT f1, O.splitdata 
FROM
 (
    SELECT *, cast('<X>' + replace(stuff(f2,1,1,''),'/','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML) as xmlfilter from @t F
 )F1
 CROSS APPLY
 ( 
    SELECT fdata.D.value('.','varchar(50)') as splitdata 
    FROM f1.xmlfilter.nodes('X') as fdata(D)
 ) O
```

This is the result:

```
f1          splitdata
02598559    04460516
04355059    04460576
04355059    05339398
04352043    04461255
```

Hopefully this points you in the right direction.